# ¿Cómo enviar una variable a una función de consulta dentro de un validacion en laravel 5.3?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5, validación

Tengo la siguiente validación en el controlador:

```
 $id=$request->id;
        $rules = array(
        'documento_identidad'=> Rule::unique('inscripcion')->where(function ($query){

            $query->where('id_evento',$id);
        }),
    );

      $mensajes = array(

        'documento_identidad.unique'=>'Ya existe en base de datos',

    );
      $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules,$mensajes);

      if ($validator->fails()){
        return Response::json(array('success'=>false,'errors' => $validator->errors()->all()));
        }
```

El problema es que la variable $id me aparece como indefinida, entonces como podria obtener esa variable en la función de consulta en la regla de 'documento_identidad'? Asumo que es porque no la estoy enviando a la funcion anonima, porque cuando establezco esa variable dentro de la funcion $id = 1; lo acepta bien, pero no cuando intento llamar una variable desde afuera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para heredar una variable en una función anónima tenes que usar "use" de la siguiente manera:

```
$id=$request->id;

$rules = array(
    'documento_identidad'=> Rule::unique('inscripcion')->where(function ($query) use ($id){
        $query->where('id_evento',$id);
    }),
);
```

Si queres leer mas sobre el tema tenes mas información [aqui](http://php.net/manual/es/functions.anonymous.php)

Comment: Muchas gracias hermano, leere la documentación @Leonardo Cabré